# TFTP pipelining protocol

Tags: udp, tftp

Wikipedia on [TFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol) states:

> Windows 2008 introduced pipelined TFTP

Its aim is to enable good throughput over high latency links. Unfortunately no reference is given. 
The only other reference I found is [Bazootftp](http://www.bazootftp.net/) mention pipelining-support.

- So how is pipelining implemented? Is it negotiated per RFC 2347?
- Is it possible to do pipelining, if only one side supports it (eg. via some ACK-tricks)?

I've seen Bazootftp add another packet-type, to signal the end of the stream.

- Is Bazootftp's pipelining the same as in Windows?
- And I haven't exactly understand, how the windowing works, esp. with lost packets.

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipelining TFTP if achived by the use of the negotiated variable "windowsize". The term pipelined is really not the best one.

you can read more here:
http://www.vercot.com/~serva/advanced/TFTP.html
and it seems probably it's going to be an RFC
http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-masotta-tftpexts-windowsize-opt/

windowsize negotiation requieres the agreement on both sides but Serva (1st link) does some tricks for getting something similar against a regular RFC-1350 TFTP client.

Comment: The RFC has just been published, [RFC 7440](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7440).